How to tell if an archive file is corrupt?
I have downloaded 424 files from www.nexusmods.com, they have a combined size of 21.576GiB.
The average download speed is 1MiB/s, because I am a non premium user and subject to NexusMods' download speed cap. The download took well over 6 hours, and I downloaded the files in batch using a Python script I wrote.
The download links are generated using the following code:
import contextlib
import json
import requests
from socket import gaierror
from requests import RequestException
from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError

DOWNLOAD_LINK_GENERATOR = (
    "https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Managers/Downloads?GenerateDownloadUrl"
)

while True:
    with contextlib.suppress(
        RequestException, HTTPError, gaierror, TimeoutError
    ):

    url = json.loads(requests.post(
        url=DOWNLOAD_LINK_GENERATOR,
        data={"fid": file_id, "game_id": game_id},
        headers=HEADERS,
        cookies=COOKIES,
        timeout=1,
   ).content)["url"]

COOKIES and HEADERS are constants loaded from a file, file_id and game_id are NexusMods ids for the file and game.
The files are downloaded using requests.get(url, stream=True), previously I used a more complicated version with aiohttp, asyncio and aiofiles, and I download the file through 16 coroutines using "Content-Range" header if the file is larger than 10MiB, with automatic retrying and cancelling download and resuming if the download speed drops to 0 for several seconds...
It was working perfectly, but somehow I couldn't make it work yesterday, so I fell back to single thread requests.get.
Now I have good reasons to suspect some files may be corrupted, first of all I am behind the Great Firewall of China, which you may or may not know. Anyway the GFW censors international internet content, throttles international network speed and outright blocks many foreign websites, like YouTube, Google and even Wikipedia.
Naturally I have ways to bypass the GFW, I can access Google, YouTube, Wikipedia and whatnot, but the services I use to access international content are also being constantly being disrupted by the GFW, then again, the service providers are actively combating it and I am actively combating the GFW as well, I learned the know-hows all by myself, I have to. But this is a war that never ends.
And this is why there are those checks in the code. Now download speed from NexusMods for non-premium users is capped, and that speed is extremely low, this compounded with the fact that NexusMods is experiencing heavy traffic due to the popularity of the Fallout TV series, all its services have "Degraded Performance", making the download speed even slower, which equals longer download time and more time for the GFW to disrupt the download process, and I have removed many checks and safeguards and error handling in my hasty reimplementation...
The files are all either .zip, .rar or .7z files (some files are named .dazip, which are just renamed .zip files), I have programmatically verified their magic numbers, all files that are supposed to be zips have magic number of b'PK\x03\x04', all 7zs b"7z\xbc\xaf'\x1c" and all rars b'Rar!\x1a\x07' (they have different eight-byte magic numbers but that is just because of the version numbers), and I intend to use Python to extract the files in batch asynchronously.
Now I have 7z.exe and I know I can use that, but I think it is unPythonic and parsing its verbose stdout (or whatever stream it uses to print to console) while easy requires unnecessary extra work. Plus these files have very bad folder structures, and there are many garbage files in the archives (.txt, .doc, .pdf, .odt and whatnot, these are readme files, there are .png, .jpg and whatnot image files, these files aren't used by the game, plus other garbage files), I would rather not extract those files. And I know I can use 7z e file to extract the files without directories, but many archives contain files with the same name in different folders, trouble is the game will only use one.
All these necessitate that I use more complex code for absolute control. And I absolutely have to do the testing before hand.
I use rarfile.RarFile for the rars, py7zr.SevenZipFile for the 7zs and zipfile.ZipFile for the zips and I have found to test the files I need to use rarfile.RarFile.testrar for the rars, py7zr.SevenZipFile.test for the 7zs and zipfile.ZipFile.testzip for the zips.
From my testing, if an archive is intact, these functions should return nothing. But if these files are corrupt, they are supposed to return the corrupted files, however I have manually made copies and corrupted the copies and they raise exceptions instead. And these exceptions are inconsistent.
I corrupted an rar file, changing the length, RarFile initializes and testrar raises rarfile.BadRarFile, BadRarFile: read failed, I corrupted the copy in a hex editor and I got this instead: BadRarFile: Corrupt file.
Corrupting 7z file, changing length, py7zr.Bad7zFile is raised when trying to initialize the object, interestingly corrupting the file without changing length, py7zr.SevenZipFile.test succeeds without returning anything, but py7zr.SevenZipFile.testzip raises LZMAError: Corrupt input data (I can't find the full name of LZMAError)
Corrupting zip file, changing length, zipfile.ZipFile.testzip raises OSError. But when I corrupt the file without changing length I noticed different behaviors:
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

and returning the corrupt file names. There is zipfile.BadZipFile and I am unable to make it get raised.
So the basic idea is to run the test function and check if it returns anything, if it returns nothing the archive is intact, but when I corrupted the files manually different exceptions are raised, and I am sure I haven't found all of them.
So if exceptions are raised, then the archive is also corrupt, the archive is corrupt if the test function returns truthy values or the function raises exceptions. Of course I know the exceptions will stop the code if I don't catch them.
I know I can use except: to catch all exceptions, but there might be other exceptions that are unrelated to corrupted files which I would rather not catch.
So what are all possible exceptions that might be raised when an archive is corrupt and these aforementioned libraries are used?

you should check documentation - it should show all special exceptions for this module. Eventually you can check source code to see what exceptions are defined in code.

frankly I wouldn't make this problem - I would add except Exception as e: print(e) to catch unexpected exceptions and print() will show them. OR I created except for known exceptions and during work I would see what else it can raise.

Fair enough, here is the code I cooked up with earlier.
I just catch all exceptions and print them, I wanted to be more specific but this should do.
import asyncio
from aiopath import AsyncPath
from aiofile import AIOFile
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from py7zr import SevenZipFile
from rarfile import RarFile
from zipfile import ZipFile
MAGIC = {}

async def get_magic(path, ext, length):
    folders = []
    with AsyncPath(path) as root:
        async for item in root.iterdir():
            if await item.is_file() and item.name.endswith(ext):
                async with AIOFile(item, mode="rb") as f:
                    MAGIC.setdefault(ext, set()).add(await f.read(length))
            elif await item.is_dir():
                folders.append(item)
    
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed([get_magic(folder, ext, length) for folder in folders]):
        await coro


def test_zip(file):
    with ZipFile(file) as f:
        return f.testzip()


def test_rar(file):
    with RarFile(file) as f:
        return f.testrar()
    

def test_7z(file):
    with SevenZipFile(file) as f:
        return f.test() or f.testzip()


ARCHIVE_VERIFIERS = (
    (".7z", test_7z),
    (".rar", test_rar),
    ((".zip", ".dazip"), test_zip)
)


def test(file):
    path = str(file).lower().replace("\\", "/")
    print("testing: " + path)
    for ext, verifier in ARCHIVE_VERIFIERS:
        if path.endswith(ext):
            try:
                if verifier(path):
                    BAD_FILES.add(path)
            except Exception as e:
                print(path + " is corrupt")
                print(e)
                BAD_FILES.add(path)
            break



BAD_FILES = set()

async def test_files_worker(directory, pool):
    folders = []
    files = []
    with AsyncPath(directory) as root:
        async for item in root.iterdir():
            if await item.is_file():
                files.append(item)
            elif await item.is_dir():
                folders.append(item)
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = (
        [loop.run_in_executor(pool, test, file) for file in files] + 
        [test_files_worker(folder, pool) for folder in folders]
    )
    
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        await coro

def test_files(directory):
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
    asyncio.run(test_files_worker(directory, pool))

The first function is what I used to get the magic numbers.
I know all the three libraries I used are synchronous so I slapped a ThreadPoolExecutor to make them asynchronous for maximum performance.
I anticipated this would take a lot of resources so that I limited the number of threads to 8, my CPU has 4 cores and I think it can handle 2 threads each core.
The RAM usage is just some hundred megabytes, there was significant disk usage, as expected, and the CPU usage is very high and the computer slowed down significantly. Which means my code is working as intended.
And here are the corrupted files:
{'d:/downloads/mods/dragonage/da2 isabela and flemeth to dao/da2dao-2636.zip',
 'd:/downloads/mods/dragonage/fine dwarven craftsmanship/fine dwarven craftsmanship-6294-1-0-1710616093.zip',
 'd:/downloads/mods/dragonage/hdr textures/hdr.2.rar',
 'd:/downloads/mods/dragonage/hdr textures/hdr.3.rar',
 'd:/downloads/mods/dragonage/hdr textures/hdr.4.rar',
 'd:/downloads/mods/dragonage/hdr textures/hdr.5.rar'}

Two files are corrupted, the last four files are split volume files, and the error was Need to start from first volume. I didn't code split volume handling and that would add extra work, anyway the point is the code works.
Anyway I have found that slapping asynchronous loop on top of synchronous functions don't make them faster, I have found async7zip and asynczip and I will probably use them, but I am unable to find "asyncrar"...

I have just found that asynczip doesn't do what I expected, it doesn't extract zip files, instead it is an asynchronous version of the built-in zip function in Python...
Also no, I have just found that async7zip doesn't provide archive information like py7zr.SevenZipFile.archiveinfo, and it doesn't even list the names, so I wouldn't use it.
